# Change colour of only one pie slice in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, color-palette

I'm creating many pie charts with varying numbers of slices. I have created a colour palette in R and specified it's values using HEX codes.

The data frame `palette` has 23 colours assigned to it, and this works fine with all of my pie charts.

My question is how I would go about changing one specific slice of a pie charts to a different colour than specified in my palette. Because my pie charts have varying numbers of slices, I cannot just change one specific HEX value in my `palette` data frame, as this would mean the colour I'd like to change would always appear on different slices of the pie charts each time.

My code looks like so:

```
ggplot(Tally_5000_7499_Sorted, aes(x = "", y = n1, fill = Haplogroup)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, size = 1) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction = -1)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = palette)+
  theme_void()+
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(title = "Haplogroup Proportion, 5000-7499 BC")+
  ggsave("5000_7499pie2.png", dpi = 1000)
```

I have the colour I'd like to specify: `#4f574e`. I have added this colour to the data frame: `Other = c("#4f574e)`

I have tried to use `scale_fill_manual(values = palette, "Other" = Other)`. This changes the correct slice but removes the colour from the rest of the pie.

I believe the solution is probably simple but I'm quite new to R and so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could set the color of a specific slice was by specifying the others by name.
I'm using the iris dataset for testing since you didn't provide a sample.

```
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = "", y = Petal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, size = 1) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction = -1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("versicolor" = "blue", "virginica" = "purple", "setosa" = "red", "This class doesn't exist" = "black")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Notice that on `scale_fill_manual` you can name classes that don't exist in your dataset, so you could create a palette with all the classes you need.